# Force my console application to Sleep/Pause/Hibernate

Tags: c#

I am running a non-threaded application that is responsible for checking the database for a file, updating the location and moving the file to a new directory.

However every Monday-Thursday-Saturday our server containing SQL Server reboots at 8:40 pm.  At 8:30 pm and until 9:00 pm or from 8-9 if that is easier I need my program to sleep.

On those days at 8pm (or 8:30 pm) I would like my program to sleep/wait/pause until 9:00 pm (I can safely assume the reboot will be finished by this time).

Is this easy/possible?  Can it be done without threading?  If I do have to use threading is it easy to implement for someone who has never used threads?

Comment: Why don't you just use the scheduler to run the app?

Comment: I agree.  Using the scheduler is by far the easiest way to handle this.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen The app runs 24/7 for the next 45 or so days.  I supposed I could use a datetime to shut my program down at 8.  Then have the schedule start it up again at 9.

Comment: Why does your application need to sleep?  Can't you just gracefully handle an exception raised when trying to connect to the SQL database?  Such as by retrying after a certain amount of time.

Comment: @TrevorElliott That would be an option as well, but I am unsure of how to do it.  I don't use try/catch blocks I use using statments not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James, Try / Catch and using are not mutually exclusive.

If the approach you decide to take is retry on SqlException you **should not**, but could use:

```
Thread.Sleep(1800000);
```

This will wait 30 minutes. Then you could try your call again. I would advise against this, but it is a quick, dirty option.

This might be [useful](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx).

You should design your application to handle the situation where database connectivity is lost. You could batch your data that you intend to write and send it all once connectivity is reestablished.

Consider rewriting this as a service. Perhaps you want to log connectivity issues.

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionProvider.ConnectionString(databaseName)))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {

            if (sqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
            //command.configure etc...
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    //retry
}
```

Comment: Can I just throw Thread.Sleep() in it and it will work out of the box, or would I have to rewrite the program to use threads?

Comment: Your program is using threads right now, but it's only using one. If you include the System.Threading namespace in your application you can tell your one thread to sleep for either a number of milliseconds or a timespan.

Comment: I wasn't going to put it into the catch block rather I was goign to grab the current time and if it is on the specified day and hour then enter this block of code and wait 30 minutes.  This way it still errors out of needed.  Thanks for the help, I think I can make this work.

Comment: @JamesWilson, you could do something like that. I posted a code block with try/catch blocks and using statements.

Comment: @JamesWilson, in fact - Jon Skeet mentions a great alternative to Thread.Sleep: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5424747/2835914)

Comment: Just a minor nit-pick: use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`, because when you do `throw ex;` the stack trace of the original exception is lost, and a new stack trace is constructed starting from that line of code. Not only is information lost, but it's also a performance hit to create another stack trace. Alternatively, don't catch the type "Exception" at all if the only thing happening in the catch block is rethrowing the exception.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice, thank you for the attention to detail! I will change my answer accordingly.