# C# multithreading game

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am new in programing expecially multithreading. I have a project for university and it is main idea is to have lots of creatures and with a metod `Update()` they change its coordinates all the time. On the other hand the user could create new creatures or to kill them by console commands. I make it with it:

```
public void Run()
{
     Thread thread = new Thread(Update);
     thread.Start();
     this.Menu();            
}
```

and in the methods Update and Menu I have `thread.Sleep(5000)`: My teacher said to make it another way. Could you recommend me something?

Comment: Formatting required!

Comment: "to make it another way" is way too broad. Not a console? Not threaded? ...

Comment: This question is far too vague and broad to be suitable here.  It sounds like you need to have a discussion with your teacher about the specific requirements of this exercise.

Comment: I can only speculate, but my money is on a non blocking thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424667/alternatives-to-thread-sleep

Comment: Multiple creatures per thread = lesser context switches = more max creature limit