# Best method to have a single thread windows service sleep for 15 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a single thread VB.net service that checks a database for specific information. If the info does not exist, it needs to wait 15 minutes and try again. What is the best method to have the service wait during this 15 minute period? I considered a Do loop with threading.thread.sleep, but am always reading how that is bad to use, but I do not know an alternative. Any suggestions of a better method for this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a Timer for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Thread.Sleep()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424667/alternatives-to-thread-sleep)

Comment: Is this actually a [Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9k985bc9%28v=VS.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?  If not, what kind of application is it?  WinForms, WPF, Console, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may, alternatively to Thread.Sleep:

1 - Make your application as SINGLE INSTANCE (see the Properties of your Solution).

2- Add an Schedule Event into Task Scheduler of the Windows to call your application on each 15 minutes.

3- Your program will be terminated normally and will be called from Windows (or manually by user).

4- Since Single-Event you won´t have many instances of the application running at the same time - just one. So, even if the Task Scheduler starts a new instance, you may be sure that just one instance will be running.

Answer (score 0):

Using a BackgroundWorker and a ManualResetEvent I think you can do what you have in mind.

```
public class LibraryBackgroundTimer : BackgroundWorker
{
    private ManualResetEvent intervalManualReset;
    public int Interval { get; set; }

    public LibraryBackgroundTimer()
    {
        this.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.Interval = 1000;
    }

    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!this.CancellationPending)
        {
                base.OnDoWork(e);
                this.Sleep();
        }
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        if (this.IsBusy)
            return;
        this.intervalManualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        this.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.CancelAsync();
        this.WakeUp();
        this.Dispose(true);
    }
    public void WakeUp()
    {
        if (this.intervalManualReset != null)
            this.intervalManualReset.Set();
    }
    private void Sleep()
    {
        if (this.intervalManualReset != null)
        {
            this.intervalManualReset.Reset();
            this.intervalManualReset.WaitOne(this.Interval);
        }
    }
}
```

using this class your timer can be stopped for a desired time and also it's capable of being waked up during the sleep time.

I hope this helps.