# Alternative to Thread.Sleep();

Tags: c#

I want a Method in C# which is going to make a break for 5 Seconds between 2 lines of codes.

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

isn't working because the rest of the code does also make a break. Have you got any Idea how to solve this?

```
falling.timespeed = 0.6f;
falling.fallingl = -50f;
// here I want a break for 5 Seconds
falling.timespeed = 1f;
falling.fallingl = -200f;
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Do you use threads?

Comment: You can call your first method, then user a timer to start your 2nd method after 5 seconds.

Comment: Use the edit link below your question and add this code to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Thread.Sleep()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424667/alternatives-to-thread-sleep)

Comment: What do you mean by _the code does also make a break_?

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with the asynchronous features in modern c#?

In c# 5 and above:

```
async Task DoSomeWork()
{
    // Do the first part of the work

    await Task.Delay(5000); // Asynchronously wait for a 5 second timer to expire.

    // Do the second part of the work
}
```

Note that, depending on the threading context that you call this method, part 2 may be executed on the same thread, or a different thread.

Comment: And, probably also important in this context, the UI has a chance to update to reflect the changes in "first part".

Comment: There are still some Errors...
http://imgur.com/kdcjOjy

Comment: @Tom you require `using` directive for `System.Threads.Tasks`.

Comment: @Gusdor Doesn't works... http://imgur.com/a/TzFCe

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I meant `System.Threading.Tasks`. If you hover over the error in the first image, and click the yellow lightbulb icon, it will give you options to automatically fix the error!

Comment: @Tom I see you are using Unity 3d. Are Coroutines more appropriate for your needs? https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines

Comment: @Gusdor Thanks for the tip. But I have now the same errors as before. The yellow lightbulb doesn't help too.

Comment: @Tom I'm afraid I do not know if unity supports async and await. This may be why you are getting the errors.

Comment: @Gusdor Are there other alternates supported by Unity?

Comment: @Tom co-routines are very close in function and more suitable for unity.