# Alternative to Thread Sleep in a while loop

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sleep

In my application I have a small number of threads (5) performing the following method non stop:

```
private void ThreadMethod()
{
     while(true)
     {
          if(CurrentItem != null)
          {
               HandleCurrentItem();
          }
          Thread.Sleep(200);
     }
}
```

From what I've seen around this is not a recommended practice, but most of the arguments is because you don't have responsiveness and you cannot cancel the thread or the timing isn't precise. None of those are an issue for me, however I'm concerned about wasting too much CPU resources in this. From what I've seen [here](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/16656?l=zAsojditC_6606218965) at 01:05:35 the processor gets full utilization when you call the Sleep method.

My questions:

Is this a decent solution in my scenario?
If not, how to do it better?

Note: I'm using .Net Framework 4.0

Note 2: those threads are located in different instances of a class, so the `CurrentItem` is a different object for each thread.

Comment: Can you provide the context for using thread. Different scenario might have different approach. Are these some kind of background task that needs to run at fixed interval?

Comment: Totally agree with Harsh - probably you don't need a loop here

Comment: I have a class that handles items in a queue. From outside anyone can enqueue a new item into one of (5) several queues that I have available. This has to be on another thread than my main application that is why I'm doing it this way. my concerns are mainly related to CPU waste doing this.

Comment: @Sturm what kind of queue do you use?

Comment: "the processor gets full utilization when you call the Sleep method" sounds like nonsense. I don't have time to watch videos right now but are you (very very) sure that's what they said?

Comment: What kind of App?  Asp.Net, WinForms, ... ?

Comment: Windows Presentation Foundation

Comment: I took a look at that video, at issue is `while (true) ;` w/o any `Sleep()`

Comment: The question is invalidated, your current approach is acceptable. But it would be solved much better as a Producer/Consumer pattern with a `BlockingCollection<>`

Comment: Yes- the questions arises from a false premise and you should investigate 'real' producer-consumer queues as suggested by @HenkHolterman.

Answer (score 6):

You could make the method `async` and make it `await`:

```
private async void ThreadMethod()
{
     while(true)
     {
         if(CurrentItem != null)
         {
             HandleCurrentItem();
         }
         await Task.Delay(200);
     }
}
```

This won't block the thread

*Note* Async await keywords will only work with `.Net 4.0` on visual studio 2012+ by using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` (you can get this package on nuget).

You can also use this snippet (credits to: [Calvin Fisher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6024667/2885376)):

```
new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1000);
```

Comment: You cannot await an `async void` method. And you should still await the `Task.Delay`.

Comment: I believe those keyword (async) are available in .Net 4.5. Furthermore I **want** to wait in this thread (I want to stop it's execution, but I don't want to waste resources of my CPU doing nothing).

Comment: @ntfrex actually had that but accidently removed it when typing the post. -_- added it back

Comment: There is no `await` in your code so `async` has no effect. Btw. OP mentions .NET 4.0, which has no async-await.

Comment: @sturm with the await keyword I just added it will wait

Comment: Ah so no async... Back in a sec

Comment: @Sturm You can use async await in 4.0 if you're on visual studio 2012+

Answer (score 3):

You could also use an `Timer` instead of sleeping when you want to execute something 200 miliseconds after the last action. This won't spin lock the processor.

```
var timer = new Timer(200);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => 
{ 
    if(CurrentItem != null)
        HandleCurrentItem(); 
};
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Start();
```

> The .NET Framework Class Library includes four classes named Timer, each of which offers different functionality:

- `System.Timers.Timer`, which fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- `System.Threading.Timer`, which executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like the System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, a Windows Forms component that fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The component has no user interface and is designed for use in a single-threaded environment; it executes on the UI thread.
- `System.Web.UI.Timer`, an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.

Comment: This looks nice, but I believe that this would go into a shared thread right? I need to take a closer look if that won't cause some unwanted side effects in my current design.

Comment: @Sturm It depends on which `Timer` class you are using. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a clean implementation by using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). This will give you more control over your tasks and you will also be getting a feedback if the function executed or failed.

You can create a scheduled job like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"),Cron.Daily);
```

There are many more options which you can explore in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AutoRestEvent

```
private void ThreadMethod()
{
    AutoResetEvent _restEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    _restEvent.Reset();
    while(true)
    {
        if(CurrentItem != null)
        {
            HandleCurrentItem();
        }
        _restEvent.WaitOne(200);   // Set a timeout in ms.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am interested in `AutoResetEvent` but since this answer has been downvoted I would like to know if this is not the way to go? Could you explain (the downvoter).

Comment: This is just  Sleep() under a different name.

Comment: ok, so what he's just asking for an alternative way for Thread.Sleep ?