# Why does an application pool for ASP.NET Core in IIS take a long time to stop?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I developed a simple demo web app using ASP.NET Core 5 and published in IIS.

However, it takes a long time (over 30 seconds) when I press application pool stop button.
Application pool cannot be started before it is stopped completed.

I have not experienced it with ASP.NET MVC 5 web app using .NET Framework 4.6.1
Application pool using ASP.NET MVC 5 can be stopped and started in a few seconds.

It may make issue with application pool idle time of IIS.

Of course, I can set application pool idle time to 0 to prevent auto shutdown of application pool.

However, I want that my web app is restarted automatically when it is idle for a long time like midnight, because my web app (not a simple demo web app but actual product) can consume very large memories.

If application restarting time is long, my web service can be down before stopping and starting is completed.

It is also important to update web app – ASP.NET Core 5 web app requires application pool shutdown to overwrite files.

If web service downtime is short (under 5 seconds), it can be acceptable to my customers.

However, if it is over 1 minite, it can be not good at real world scenario.

Is there any way to decrease application pool restarting time of ASP.NET Core 5 on IIS?

Comment: You can add a simple website and create a new app pool for it. Then test the pool's stop and start time, check if it need 5 seconds.

Comment: I already tested it by creating simple web site (static web site containing html, css, js and C# code was almost same to ASP.NET Core 5 web app template of Visual Studio 2019) as I wrote in the question and it took over 30s to stop application pool.
It was stopped quickly when I have not visited it, but stopping time was increased after any visit.

Comment: Even the simplest applications may take a long time to stop the application pool, indicating that the performance of the entire server is limited by the hardware. CPU, memory. . . .

Comment: @BruceZhang my laptop is Ryzen 4750u (8 cores 16 threads) and 32GB RAM and 2TB SSD. How long does it usually take to stop ASP.NET Core 5 application pool on IIS in general? I want to know my situation is normal or not.

Comment: General is less than 30s, almost 5 seconds. Please try to reinstall IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- Using Thread.Sleep somewhere in application. When thread is sleeping, [IIS waits](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.initiateshutdown?view=netframework-4.8) for 30 sec (by default, [can be configured in web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.hostingenvironmentsection.shutdowntimeout?view=netframework-4.8)). Thread.Sleep can be replaced by await Task.Delay (see more variants [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424667/alternatives-to-thread-sleep))
- Using HttpClient in some objects destructors
- Some another work in objects destructors.

I investigated similar problem by sequently removing code from application and trying to stop pool.