# Chart Upgrade in C# make Lagging Application

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

WindowForm Application, i'm trying to use chart for displaying Datafrom serial port connected to an arduino.
I can read my data and save them to a table in an array after formating the serial data :

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialDataIn = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var charsToRemove = new string[] { "\r" };
    foreach ( var c in charsToRemove)
    {
        serialDataIn = serialDataIn.Replace(c, string.Empty);
    }
    data = serialDataIn.Split('\n');
    data = data.Take(data.Count() - 1).ToArray();
    if(pulse_Generated==true)
    {
        dataPulse = data;
        dataMultiPulse = dataMultiPulse.Concat(dataPulse).ToArray();
        pulse_Generated = false;
        Display_MultiPulse();
        Display_Pulse();
    }
    Display();
}
```

After than, i'm trying to update 3 chart.

The first one is updated after each data reception (~500ms):

```
private void Display()
{
    chSignal.Series.Clear();
    chSignal.Series.Add("Serie1");
    chSignal.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    // Add point to chart
    for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
    {
        chSignal.Series[0].Points.AddXY(j, data[j]);  
    } 
    Array.Clear(data, 0, data.Length);

    //Temporisation pour l'affichage
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Restart_Measure();
}
```

The seconde and the third one are updated after à click button (Pulse generation):

```
*Seconde one*
private void Display_Pulse()
{
    chPulse.Series.Clear();
    chPulse.Series.Add("Serie1");
    chPulse.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    // Add point to chart
    for (int j = 0; j < dataPulse.Length; j++)
    {
        chPulse.Series[0].Points.AddXY(j, dataPulse[j]);
    }
    Array.Clear(dataPulse, 0, dataPulse.Length);


    //Temporisation pour l'affichage
    Thread.Sleep(500);

}

*Third one*
private void Display_MultiPulse()
{

    var graphDonnee = chMultiPulse.ChartAreas[0];
    graphDonnee.AxisX.Maximum = dataMultiPulse.Length - 1;
    chMultiPulse.Series.Clear();
    chMultiPulse.Series.Add("Serie1");
    chMultiPulse.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    // Add point to chart
    for (int j = 0; j < dataMultiPulse.Length; j++)
    {
        chMultiPulse.Series[0].Points.AddXY(j, dataMultiPulse[j]);
    }
}
```

The first two work normaly. But the third one updating only when i stop the serial communication betwin my WinFormApp and my arduino.

Further, when a want to generate a "pulse" commande. Normaly i write in a rich text box the pulse characteristic. And the rich text box only update when i stoped the serial communication (as the third chart).

My question is, where my code become blocking ? I go 2 chart out of 3 that work fine.

Comment: As an experiment, what happens if you change `this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));` to `this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));` ?

Comment: I'm not up to date with win forms as most projects I work with are converted to WPF decades ago... however I guess async/await programming may also be available for win forms?

Comment: @Mat: They are indeed.  Even before Task-based async/await, however, there were many better alternatives to `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: @Mat Should i try to convert my WinApp in WPF ? But for me converting into WPF is a big job. And i don't know where i can find some good WPF app introduction.

Comment: During my research. I find this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424667/alternatives-to-thread-sleep). It talk about other than using `thread.sleep(...)` for making temporisation.
And the first comment suggest to replace `thread.sleep` by `ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(...)`.
This new way to make temporisation look good in my application. It is sill slow, but now i can see all of my chart.